# Using Zend Framework 2 + Doctrine2.3 with ObjectSelect and ManyToOne relations

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form

I"m having a bit of trouble with using Doctrine's ObjectSelect on ManyToOne relations.

The relations I have below using ManyToMany work 100% adding and editing. My edit form is populated with the current selection without any problems.

The issue arises with the ManyToOne relations, it appears the form is not being populated with the current selection.

I have tried dumping the Task entity before I bind it to the form and it looks 100% right, all my relations are populated in the entity.

However after binding it, the form is being displayed without the current value selected.

Task entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tasks")
 */
class Task
{

        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;
    ...
        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        protected $category;
    ...    
        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ZDUser\Entity\User")
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="tasks_assigned_user_linker",
         *        joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="task_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
         *        inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
         * )
         */
        protected $assignedUsers;

        /**
         * Initialize
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->assignedUsers = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        /**
         * We need a few getters and setters
         */
        public function getId()
        {
                return $this->id;
        }
        public function setId($id)
        {
                $this->id = $id;
        }

        public function getCategory() {
                return $this->category;
        }
        public function setCategory(Category $category) {
                $this->category = $category;
        }

        public function getAssignedUsers() {
                return $this->assignedUsers;
        }
        public function addAssignedUsers(Collection $users) {
                foreach ($users as $user) {
                        $this->assignedUsers->add($user);
                }
        }
        public function removeAssignedUsers(Collection $users) {
                foreach ($users as $user) {
                        $this->assignedUsers->removeElement($user);
                }
        }
}
```

I'm using ManyToOne in most of my entities, I find this way a little easier and extensible going forward. I can just add addtional entities and link them to other ones without having to do relations on both sides.

Category Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="task_categories")
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $name
 */
class Category
{
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
         */
        protected $name;
  ...
        /**
         * Setters and getters we need
         */
        public function getId()
        {
                return $this->id;
        }
        public function setId($id)
        {
        $this->id = (int) $id;
        }

        public function getName()
        {
                return $this->name;
        }
        public function setName($name)
        {
                $this->name = $name;
        }

}
```

User Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, ProviderInterface
{
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;
    ...
        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ZDUser\Entity\Group")
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_groups_linker",
         *        joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
         *        inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
         * )
         */
        protected $groups;

        /**
         * Initialies the object
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        /* Getters and setters, we must define these for the implementation to work */
        public function getId()
        {
                return $this->id;
        }
        public function setId($id)
        {
                $this->id = (int) $id;
        }

        /* Get and add groups */
        public function getGroups()
        {
            return $this->groups;
        }
        public function addGroup(Group $group)
        {
            $this->groups->add($group);
        }
```

Form code:

```
class TaskForm extends Form implements ObjectManagerAwareInterface
{
        protected $objectmanager;

        public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
        {
                // we want to ignore the name passed
                parent::__construct('task');


                $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($em,'TaskList\Entity\Task'));

                $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
                $this->add(array(
                        'name' => 'id',
                        'attributes' => array(
                                'type'  => 'hidden',
                        ),
                ));

                $this->add(array(
                        'name' => 'subject',
                        'type'  => 'Text',
                        'options' => array(
                                'label' => 'Subject',
                        ),
                ));

                $this->add(array(
                        'name' => 'category',
                        'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
                        'options' => array(
                                'label' => "Category",
                                'object_manager' => $em,
                                'target_class' => 'TaskList\Entity\Category',
                                'property' => 'name',
                        ),
                ));


                $this->add(array(
                        'name' => 'assignedUsers',
                        'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
                        'attributes' => array(
                                'multiple' => 'multiple',
                        ),
                        'options' => array(
                                'label' => "Assigned To (User)",
                                'object_manager' => $em,
                                'target_class' => 'ZDUser\Entity\User',
                                'property' => 'email',
                        ),
                ));
```

Controller for Edit & Add:

```
    public function addAction()
    {
            $this->addedit();

            // Grab form
            $form = new TaskForm($this->getEntityManager());

            // Grab any request we may have
            $request = $this->getRequest();

            // If it a post ...
            if ($request->isPost()) {
                    $task = new Task();
                    $form->bind($task);

                    // Populate data
                    $form->setData($request->getPost());

                    // Check if the form is valid
                    if ($form->isValid()) { 
                            // Setup some things we need
                            $task->setCreated(new \DateTime("now"));

                            // Save
                            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($task);
                            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

                            // Redirect to list of tasks
                            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('tasklist'); 
                    }
            }

            return array(
                    'form' => $form
            );
    }


    public function editAction()
    {
            $this->addedit();

            // Get ID or redirect
            $id = (int)$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('id');
            if (!$id) {
                    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('tasklist');
            }

            // Create a form
            $form = new TaskForm($this->getEntityManager());

            // Grab entity from doctrine
            $task = $this->getEntityManager()->find('TaskList\Entity\Task', $id);

            // Bind the form to the task 
            $form->bind($task);

            // Check if we have a request and if its POST
            $request = $this->getRequest();

            if ($request->isPost()) {
                    // If it is, set the form data from the request
                    $form->setData($request->getPost());

                    // If the form is valid, bind the values
                    if ($form->isValid()) {
                            // Setup some things we need
                            $task->setLastUpdated(new \DateTime("now"));

                            // Flush the update
                            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

                            // Redirect to list of tasks
                            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('tasklist');
                    }
            }

            return array(
                    'id' => $id,
                    'form' => $form,
            );
    }
```

I'm so sure I'm missing something really simple.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, see [this issue](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/issues/122) on the DoctrineORMModule GitHub for more info.

It's something to do with Doctrine not returning the correct ID field from metadata when Proxies Entities are loaded. The solutions are as follows:

1. Wait for official fix in Doctrine 2.4 (you can install 2.4-beta2 now!).
2. Subclass the ObjectSelect to force the use of the correct ID field (someone in the aforelinked issue did this).
3. Patch DoctrineModule with this:

   ```
   --- doctrine/doctrine-module/src/DoctrineModule/Form/Element/Proxy.php  2013-03-11 17:49:55.406011600 -0300
   +++ doctrine/doctrine-module/src/DoctrineModule/Form/Element/Proxy.php  2013-03-11 17:51:33.592710900 -0300
   @@ -240,7 +240,10 @@
                    if (count($identifier) > 1) {
                        //$value = $key;
                    } else {
   -                    $value = current($metadata->getIdentifierValues($value));
   +                    // Doctrine has a bug that makes the following not work, 
   +                    // this is a horrible workaround until Doctrine 2.4 is released with a fix.
   +                    //$value = current($metadata->getIdentifierValues($value));
   +                    $value = $value->getId();
                    }
                }
            }
   ```

The `$value->getId()` relies on that method being available in the corresponding entity. This isn't recommended but a quick fix.

Comment: Do you have a link to the commit?

Comment: No sorry, you'd have to hit up the Doctrine guys for that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the right way?  I posted my idea to their ML :)
Probably not the right way?  I posted my idea to their ML :)

```
diff --git a/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php b/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php
index cba525a..2f62375 100644
--- a/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php
+++ b/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php
@@ -667,7 +667,17 @@ class ClassMetadataInfo implements ClassMetadata
             return $id;
         }

-        $value = $this->reflFields[$this->identifier[0]]->getValue($entity);
+
+               /**
+                * NK: First try use the getter, in the case of a proxied object, the reflection is not going to work
+                * as the proxied object does not have any properties
+                */
+               $getter = 'get' . ucfirst($this->identifier[0]);
+               if (method_exists($entity, $getter)) {
+                       $value = $entity->$getter();
+               } else {
+               $value = $this->reflFields[$this->identifier[0]]->getValue($entity);
+               }
```